# When Set.insert() returns oldMember that is distinguishable from newMember?

Tags: swift, set

The documentation for `Set`'s `insert` method [states](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/set/1541375-insert):

> **Return Value**
>
> `(true, newMember)` if `newMember` was not contained in the set. If an element equal to `newMember` was already contained in the set, the method returns `(false, oldMember)`, where `oldMember` is the element that was equal to `newMember`.
>
> In some cases, `oldMember` may be distinguishable from `newMember` by identity comparison or some other means.

What are the cases when `oldMember` might be distinguishable from `newMember` they are talking about?  Any example?

Reason for the question:  I have a `Set` that contains objects that are not necessarily `Hashable`.  I had the idea to use `Unmanaged.passUnretained(object).toOpaque().hashValue` to get a hash-value for just any object (basically from its address) in a wrapper struct, however the above bit in the documentation makes me wary.

Comment: Note that a simpler way of getting a `hashValue` based on the object address would be `ObjectIdentifier(object).hashValue`

Comment: @Hamish, thanks for the tip with `ObjectIdentifier`, btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have some way to tell two instances apart *even when* they compare equal by their implementation of `Equatable`'s `==` operator, then you can use this to compare the element to insert with the `memberAfterInsert` returned by `insert(_:)`.

A prime example of this, as the documentation says, is the identity comparison (`===`). Two object instances that compare equal may not necessarily be the *exact* same instance (i.e have the same address).

For example:

```
class Foo : Hashable {

    static func ==(lhs: Foo, rhs: Foo) -> Bool {
        return lhs.foo == rhs.foo
    }

    var hashValue: Int {
        return foo
    }

    let foo: Int

    init(_ foo: Int) {
        self.foo = foo
    }
}

var set : Set = [Foo(10)]

let toInsert = Foo(10)
let result = set.insert(toInsert) // the element toInsert will compare equal to the element
                                  // already in the set, thus the element already in the
                                  // already in the set will be returned.

print(result) // (false, Foo) – false, as element was already in set
print(result.memberAfterInsert == toInsert) // true – obviously they were equal.
print(result.memberAfterInsert === toInsert) // false – but they weren't the same instance.
```

In your case of using a hash value based on the identity, as long as your `Equatable` implementation also relies on the identity, you won't break the contract of `Hashable` (instances that compare equal with `==` must have the same `hashValue`) – although obviously you won't be able to use the identity to differentiate the `memberAfterInsert` with the element you are trying to insert.

However it's worth noting that having a `Set` where the `Element`'s equality implementation is solely based on identity may cause surprising results for objects that look like they *should* be equivalent. For example, it would be perfectly fine to have a set of `[Foo(5), Foo(5), Foo(5), Foo(5)]`, given that the objects are different instances.

Comment: Thanks for this example.  To clarify the passage, "In your case of using a hash value based on the identity... obviously you won't be able to use the identity to differentiate the memberAfterInsert with the element you inserted".  I would expect in this case that the the insertion to return `false` only when object being inserted is really already there, right?  So identity check would still work.

Comment: @AntonBronnikov An identity check between the element to insert and the `memberAfterInsert` would always return true – as if the `==` is based on identity, then in the case of an identical element already being in the set, that element would be returned and compare true with the element to insert. In the case of the element not already being in the set, the element to insert will be passed straight back out of the function, again comparing true.